# Magento 2 product image is blank

Tags: magento2, product-images

I'm trying to write an observer and send product data to external source.

Have everything done except that when I get image it shows default Magento image.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imgHelper
) {
     $this->_order = $order;
     $this->_product = $product;
     $this->_imgHelper = $imgHelper;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
    ...
    $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach($itemCollection as $item){
        $product = $this->_product->load($item->getData('product_id'));
        $this->_imgHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
    }
    ....
}
```

The image which I get is:

> http://convert.wemessage.it/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/dc09e1c71e492175f875827bcbf6a37

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

First please check whether product object is loaded successfully or not by fetching id using `$product->getId()` if product object is fine then Try to use this

```
$this->_imgHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->getUrl();
```

instead of this

```
$this->_imgHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->getUrl();
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: same result:
http://convert.wemessage.it/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/dc09e1c71e492175f875827bcbf6a37

Comment: Please check in admin for particular product whether there is an image to assign to that or not

Comment: Try to use this `$this->_imgHelper->init($product, 'product_base_image')->getUrl();` as well if there is image assign to that product

Comment: image is Assigned to base, thumbnail, small, swatch.
with base image also same: http://convert.wemessage.it/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/6517c62f5899ad6aa0ba23ceb3eeff9

Comment: Please flush the catalog images cache and also do product related indexing if it's invalidated

Comment: cleared cache reindexed ( magento is in developer mode ) .. result still same :

http://convert.wemessage.it/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/6517c62f5899ad6aa0ba23ceb3eeff9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90864/discussion-between-muhammad-hasham-and-naberd-zendi).

Answer (score 0):

damn it seem to be i had error in external source, limit of file name there was 100 chars..